# Creating a case with createRecord LWC error/trouble

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, ui-api

I'm just trying to create a simple LWC that creates a case record from a button click. When I add the component to the account page and click the create button nothing is happening, there are no errors. If I run the LWC from within a aura app I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: n.createRecord is not a function`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Heres the code for the LWC:

***.html***

```
 <template>
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Quick Case" icon-name="standard:case">
        <div class ="slds-m-around_small">
            <lightning-input name="subject" 
                             value={subject} 
                             type="text" 
                             label="Case Subject" 
                             onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-textarea name="description" 
                                value={description} 
                                label="Case Description" 
                                onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-textarea>
            <lightning-combobox name="CaseStatus"
                                label="Case Status"
                                value={statusValue}
                                placeholder="Select Status"
                                options={pickValStatus}
                                onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
            <lightning-combobox name="CaseOrigin"
                        label="Case Origin"
                        value={originValue}
                        placeholder="Select Origin"
                        options={pickValOrigin}
                        onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
            <lightning-combobox name="CasePriority"
                        label="Case Priority"
                        value={priorityValue}
                        placeholder="Select Priority"
                        options={pickValPriority}
                        onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
            <br/>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" 
                              label="Create Case" 
                              onclick={handleCreate}
            ></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

***.js***

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValuesByRecordType, createRecord } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';

import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Status';
import ORIGIN_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Origin';
import PRIORITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.ContactId';

export default class QuickCaseAssignment extends LightningElement {
    subject;
    description;
    statusValue;
    originValue;
    priorityValue;

    pickValStatus;
    pickValOrigin;
    pickValPriority;

    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName; 
    
    objectName; 

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT })
        accountMetadata;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { 
            recordTypeId : '$accountMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId', 
            objectApiName : CASE_OBJECT
        }) 
        wiredRecordTypeInfo({data, error}) {
            if(data) {
                console.log(' getPicklistValuesByRecordType Info : ', data);
                this.pickValStatus = data.picklistFieldValues.Status.values;
                this.pickValOrigin = data.picklistFieldValues.Origin.values;
                this.pickValPriority = data.picklistFieldValues.Priority.values;
            }
            if(error) {
                console.log('Error Occurred : ', error);
            }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let name = event.target.name;
        let val = event.target.value;
        if(name === 'subject'){
            this.subject = val;
        } else if (name === 'description') {
            this.description = val;
        } else if (name === 'CaseStatus') {
            this.statusValue = val;
        } else if (name === 'CaseOrigin') {
            this.originValue = val;
        } else if (name === 'CasePriority') {
            this.priorityValue = val;
        } 
    }

    handleCreate() {
        console.log('*** recordId *** ' + this.recordId);
        console.log('*** objectApiName *** ' + this.objectApiName);
        console.log('*** statusValue *** ' + this.statusValue);
        console.log('*** originValue *** ' + this.originValue);
               
        const fields = {};
        fields[STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.statusValue;
        fields[ORIGIN_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.originValue;
        fields[PRIORITY_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.priorityValue;
        const caseRecord = {apiName : CASE_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields : fields};
        
        createRecord(caseRecord)
            .then(result => {
                //const id = result.id;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Case created: ' + result.id,
                        variant: 'success',
                    }),
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            }) 
            console.log('*** end createRecord *** ');
    }
}
```

***.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the createRecord method like this.

```
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

Also remove createRecord from this line

```
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValuesByRecordType, createRecord } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```